# Google Sheet Conditional Formatting Based on Date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

So I want to have a cell change red if the date in that cell is 2 months from todays date. (contract end date is 17th July, 1 month from now, cell is red)

I have put:

`=Today()` in cell `Y3`

`=($Y$3-$B3)` in cell `Z3` and dragged it down, as all dates are different

And then in Column `B:B` where the dates are I condition formatted - custom formula is and put `=AND(($Z3>0), ($Z3<60))`

Not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use conditional formatting on the column`B:B`.

Set the custom formula to:

```
=AND(B1 <> "", ROW(B1) >= 3, EDATE(TODAY(), 2) > B1)
```

`ROW(B1) >= 3` - assuming your data starts from the 3rd row.

Comment: Fixed a small thing.